# Start app on remote machine

Tags: windows-7, rdp, users, accounts

I have a remote machine running windows 7.  It has two users.  It has the default user with no password which is used for home theater purposes.  I have a separate login I use for remote desktop.
I would like to be able to be able to remote into my account and use a console command to start an application on the local login account.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use powershell. Windows 7 shipped with powershell 2.0, which has a lot of great remote utilities.

You can either [open a new tab to a remote shell](http://halr9000.com/article/690), or use [winrm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384372(VS.85).aspx). These are both "native".

Answer (score 2):

[PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) sounds like the app you are looking for.

```
psexec \\computer -u user -p psswd  cmd [arguments]
```

There are a lot of options such as which session to use as well.

Comment: Do you need to specify "-i 1" (or some other Session ID) for Windows 7? Just curious, I haven't tried psexec on RTM Windows 7, this used to be an issue with the pre-release versions.

Comment: Is there a way to start a remote app without using third party software?  Aside from logging into that user of course.

-Helvick, I don't know anything about session IDs.

Comment: @Helvick - not sure about the session number. I am trying to test it myself.

Answer (score -1):

I may have an answer, but I don't want to give you something that won't let you achieve the desired result.

Can you tell us why you need to launch an application as the other user?

Comment: The remote machine hosts all of my torrent downloading as it is usually on.  I would like to be able to remote start bittorrent so I may log in via uTorrent.
Normally I would use remote desktop however that would log off whoever is watching TV.